# How do I get past the end of the world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I go to 29,999,999.999 in the x coordinate, I see a barrier in which I can not go through. But that is in the latest update of 1.7.9. What version do I have to go back to to get farther than 29,999,999.999? Equally, I seem to have normal world generation after a couple hundred blocks of the big mountain blocks of land. I want an infinite amount of that. Which version I have to be in or something like that?

Comment: I need to know for next time I visit near there.

Comment: There is a barrier of sorts at 30.000.000, for the 1.7 version, referenced [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/World_boundary#1.7), which would explain your phenomena.

Answer (score 13):

In versions before Beta 1.8 there was the "[Far Lands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Far_Lands)" at 12,550,745 Blocks from the center of the Minecraft World where the world generation bugged up and causing extreme performance issues and crashing.

It was fixed unintentionally in Beta 1.8 with the new terrain generation. before the fix if you was running a 64-bit version of Java the chance of the game crashing was high at 4,000,000,000 and obviously higher as you went further in.

at 34,359,738,368 chunks will start getting overwritten as such a Minecraft world isn't infinite, at the distance indicated older chunks will no longer exists however considering the risk of the game crashing at 4,000,000,000 and how long it would take to reach 34,359,738,368 the odds of someone ever seeing that is very, very, very unlikely (due to the game crashing all the time)